# React: Argument type function(any): any & {enteredTitle: any} is not assignable to parameter type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea

I am following a React course and I have the following code:

```
const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState({
    enteredTitle: "",
    enteredAmount: "",
    enteredDate: ""
})

function titleChangeHandler(event) {
    setUserInput((prevState) => {
        return {
            ...prevState,
            enteredTitle: event.target.value
        }
    })
}
```

I am getting the following error in my IDE:

```
Argument type function(any): any & {enteredTitle: any} is not assignable to parameter type ((prevState: {enteredAmount: string, enteredTitle: string, enteredDate: string}) => {enteredAmount: string, enteredTitle: string, enteredDate: string}) | {enteredAmount: string, enteredTitle: string, enteredDate: string}   Type string is not assignable to type undefined     Type function(any): any & {enteredTitle: any} is not assignable to type (prevState: {enteredAmount: string, enteredTitle: string, enteredDate: string}) => {enteredAmount: string, enteredTitle: string, enteredDate: string}
```

When I default back to my old implementation, it works fine:

```
function titleChangeHandler(event) {
    setUserInput({
        ...userInput,
        enteredTitle: event.target.value,
    })
}
```

JSX implementation:

```
return (
    <form>
        <div className="new-expense__controls">
            <div className="new-expense__control">
                <label>Title</label>
                <input type="text" onChange={titleChangeHandler} />
            </div>
            <div className="new-expense__control">
                <label>Amount</label>
                <input type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" onChange={amountChangeHandler} />
            </div>
            <div className="new-expense__control">
                <label>Date</label>
                <input type="date" min="2019-01-01" max="2024-12-31" onChange={dateChangeHandler} />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="new-expense__actions">
            <button type="submit">Add Expense</button>
        </div>
    </form>
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using IntelliJ IDEA and JavaScript (not TypeScript).

Comment: Can you show the jsx implementation part where you are using titleChangeHandler?

Comment: @programandoconro Done. I'm also suspecting this may be an IDE bug what do you think?

Comment: is your code still working as expected?

Comment: @programandoconro yes, it is.

Comment: so maybe you should tag the question with IntelliJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is tracked at [WEB-55655](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-55655/Type-mismatch-error-reported-for-setter-returned-from-useState-when-using-spreads), please vote for it to get notified when it's fixed

Comment: Thank you, but please fix this. I've now disabled the inspection, but this does give a bad user experience.